# Localization html static text

Tags: asp.net, localization, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net globalization difference in inline tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017960/asp-net-globalization-difference-in-inline-tags)

I read on MSDN about localization of static text and Localize control but I still don't understand: how should I localize for example a html table's static text?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%=Resources.Resource1.String1 %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%=Resources.Resource1.String2 %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Localize ID="Column1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: Resource1, String1 %>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Localize ID="Column2" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: Resource1, String2 %>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The first is obviously is more readable and I don't need to change translations on runtime. Maybe it has some disadvantages vs second? I'm sorry for my stupid question but I want to be sure that way which I'll select will be more preferable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples you showed do not really make any difference. The first one will be easier to code - you will see IntelliSense (code completion) hint.

Personally I prefer [Implicit Localization](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/localization/implicit-and-explicit-localization/) for it will give you defaults and I feel the code is less cluttered:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Localize ID="Column1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Column2" Text="Column 1 name" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Localize ID="Column2" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Column1" Text="Column 2 name" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also, I find App_LocalResources to be a better way for Localizing Asp.Net applications - you would need to split your translation into several .resx files, which might be just easier to maintain in large code base (for example it would be easier to use [Translation Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory) software; it should cost less).
For more information on Implicit Localization, see my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017960/asp-net-globalization-difference-in-inline-tags/6022857#6022857).

Answer (score 0):

The second one will give you a Control whose ID you can reference from code to change on the fly.  The first one does not have this ability.  For example:

```
if (condition)
    Column1.Text += " - 123";
else
    Column1.Text += " - 456";
```

Comment: Thank God it does not. What you showed here is a well known Localizability defect - the Concatenation. If you need to "append" strings, you should use String.Format().

Comment: @Pawel: Can you give me a reference for your comment?

Comment: Please find one of my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298791/problem-when-concatenating-string-and-a-resource-value/5307413#5307413) that contains example. I am not sure what you mean by "reference".

Comment: @Pawel: By reference I mean the documentation for your assertion.